# the remote server returned an error (403) forbidden - while connect sharepoint using c#

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to get the list items from SharePoint. While executing the following code, I am getting "the remote server returned an error (403) forbidden".

```
 try
        {
            using (var context = new ClientContext(siteurl + "/_api/lists/GetByTitle('" + documentlibrary + "')/items?$orderby=Id%20desc"))
            {
                context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("username@abcd.com", GetPasswordOfYourSite("password"));
                Web web = context.Web;
                context.Load(web.Lists,
                    lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title,
                        list => list.Id));
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                foreach (List list in web.Lists)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("List title is: " + list.Title);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error is: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

while trying to connect, getting this "the remote server returned an error (403) forbidden" exception.

Could you please what are the reasons for this issue? and how to resolve this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
using(var context = new ClientContext(siteurl + "/_api/lists/GetByTitle('" + documentlibrary + "')/items?$orderby=Id%20desc"))
```

to

```
using (var context = new ClientContext(siteurl))
```

The syntax you are passing in ClientContext is used in REST and not in .Net Managed code. Here only siteurl will do the job and should fix your 403 error.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line

```
using (var context = new ClientContext(siteurl + "/_api/lists/GetByTitle('" + documentlibrary + "')/items?$orderby=Id%20desc"))
```

to this

```
using (var context = new ClientContext(siteurl))
```

The URL you pass to the ClientContext constructor should be the URL to a site collection. You added a SharePoint REST API resource URL to that URL. This is unnecessary because the remainder of your code uses the SharePoint Client Object Model to implement the desired functionality.

You can get more information on the REST API and the Client Object Model by reviewing the materials for my conference talk: [Introduction to the SharePoint Client Object Model and REST API](http://bit.ly/WindsorCsomRest)